# How to get distinct elements from flux iterable

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have 3 objects. Foo composed of set of Bars and Bar is composed of set of baz . Given Foo, How should I iterate and use distinct() to get distinct baz and distinct bars?

I have below code:

```java
//Updated
class Foo{

     Integer fooId;
     Set<Integer> barSetOfIds ;
      //getter&setter
}

and FooRepo{
        Mono<Foo> find(Integer fooId);
    }
class Bar{
  Integer barId;
  Set<Integer> bazSetOfIds ;
//getter&setter
}
and BarRepo{
        Mono<Bar> find(Integer barId);
    }

class Baz{
     Integer bazId;
}

and BazRepo{
   Flux<Baz> find(Integer bazid);
}
```

So actually I tried this

Calling code:
///some method

```java
Mono<Boolean> monoPresent = fooRepo
       .find(fooId)
       .filter(i -> i.getFooId() != null)
       .hasElement();

   return monoPresent.flatMap(isPresent -> {
         if (isPresent) {
           return fooRepo.find(fooId)
               .map(fooFromDB -> {//fooFromDB is instance of Foo returned
                 fooRepo.update(fooFromDB);
                 return processDistinct(fooFromDB);
               })
               .then();
         } else {//
           return Mono.error(new SomeException("foo")
               .then();
         }
       }
   );

//below method gets called 

Flux<Integer> processDistinct(Foo pkg) {
   System.out.println("INSIDE ");
   Flux<Integer> cids = Flux.fromIterable(pkg.getBarListIds())
       .flatMap(p ->
           {
             System.out.println("barInteger=" + p.intValue());
             return barRepo.find(p);
           }
       ).flatMapIterable(
           x -> {
             System.out.println("cids=" + x.getBazListIds().size());
             return x.getBazListIds();
           }
       )
       .distinct()
       .doOnNext(x -> System.out.println("Inside doOnNext=" + x));
   //So here only on block do I see distinct values printed else code just passes
   List<Integer> list2 = cids.collectSortedList().block();
   list2.forEach(cidints -> System.out.println("cids=" + cidints));

   return cids;
 }
```

I can see cids(variables) values printed only when I block()

UPDATE:
Using Michael's suggestion (with some changes)Below approach in processDistinct also works but still need to block which leads to my suspicion in calling code and not in processDistict[?].

```java
processDistinct(Foo foo){
Flux<Integer> distinctBazzFluxIds = fooRepo
       .find(foo.getFooId())
       .flatMapIterable(Foo::getBarSetOfIds)
       .flatMap(barId -> {
         return barRepo.find(barId);
       }).flatMapIterable(bar-> bar.getBazSetOdIds()).distinct()
       .doOnNext(bazId -> {
         System.out.println("Inside doOnNext"+cid);
         new SomeService().sendDistinct(cid);
       });
```

UPDATE(Fixed):
So I was stupid to call this processDistinct from inside of doOnNext of calling streams and I think the stream was getting lost( I need some better explanation). I fixed this and now it works. But not sure of correct explanation why and where the stream was getting lost.

```java
    Mono<Boolean> monoPresent = fooRepo
        .find(fooId)
        .filter(i -> i.getFooId() != null)
        .hasElement();

    return monoPresent.flatMap(isPresent -> {
      if (isPresent) {
        return fooRepo
            .find(foo.getFooId())
            .flatMapIterable(Foo::getBarSetOfIds)
            .flatMap(barId -> {
              return barRepo.find(barId);
            }).flatMapIterable(bar -> bar.getBazSetOdIds()).distinct()
            .doOnNext(bazId -> {
              System.out.println("Inside doOnNext" + cid);
              new SomeService().sendDistinct(cid);
            }).then();
      } else {//SAVE
        return Mono.error(new SomeException("foo")
            .then();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class structure and your question don't match - At present both `Foo` and `Bar` contain sets of `Integer`, not `Bar` and `Baz` respectively, and your `Repo` classes are already returning `Flux`, not iterable.

Assuming that the question text is correct, you would have a class structure similar to the following:

```
class Foo {
    Integer fooId;
    Set<Bar> barSet;
}

class Bar {
    Integer barId;
    Set<Baz> bazSet;
}

class Baz {
    Integer bazId;
}

interface FooRepo {
    Iterable<Foo> findAll();
}
```

...then you can then use the following to obtain (for example) all distinct `Baz` objects:

```
Flux<Baz> distinctBazzFlux = Flux.fromIterable(fooRepoInstance.findAll())
        .flatMapIterable(Foo::getBars)
        .flatMapIterable(Bar::getBazs)
        .distinct();
```

If you just want the distinct `Bar` objects, remove the second `flatMapIterable()` call.

Specifically, you need the `flatMapIterable()` method as the `flatMap()` method can only flatten a `Publisher` (such as another `Flux` or `Mono`). You could of course wrap your iterable inside a `Flux` first, but `flatMapIterable()` is a far neater and more concise method of obtaining the same result.

If, as per your comment, the classes contain sets of integers rather than the objects themselves, then you can take a similar approach:

```
Flux<Baz> distinctBazzFlux = fooRepo.find(blah)
        .flatMapIterable(Foo::getBars)
        .map(BarRepo::find)
        .flatMapIterable(Bar::getBazs)
        .map(BazRepo::find)
        .distinct();
```

In any case, blocking is the wrong solution, as that essentially defeats the point of using reactor in the first place.

Comment: I updated the post. Actually , parent objects contains child ids . So your approach could not work.I tried another approach but I can only see distinct child integers printed when i block.

Comment: I am using Flux.fromIterable inside that helper so it is new stream. Not sure if block is ok or not

Comment: Also, finders return Mono . I had wrongly posted other findAll which would return all rows. It sould be one row from parent.

Comment: @VivekMisra See the updated answer, you can still take a similar approach, you just need to map your IDs to the corresponding objects. If that still doesn't help then you need to be *much* clearer in your question what it is you're after, provide syntactically correct code, and format it properly.

Comment: @Micahel Berry .Tried ur approach. flatMapIterable(Bar::getBazs) gave me error :"Non static methods cannot be referenced from static context"/ So I  fixed (see in original post). After distinct() I need to call a method on these distinct ids & i call doOnNext but still it did not print still  I need to use block to get it printed. I think issue may be in calling code. I will paste my approach & also format code.

Comment: We dont need to go till Bar::getBazs. We get it already bar.getBazSetOfIds() . and apply distinct. Right?

Comment: So I updated code and looks like calling code has issue. it is fixed but  I dont know the actual cause/bug . You can review updated code & let me know where was issue.